# JavaScript array push method not displaying all elements after pushing

Tags: javascript, arrays, jqgrid

I am working on a javascript array. I am getting a list from the backend of size 122. But I am pushing all the elements into a javascript array and displaying all of them in UI. But only 30 are visible in display.

I amusing JQGrid javascript frame work for grid display. Need some help to know what I am missing here. :(

Please find the code below:

```
var list= '<%=list%>';
alert(list.length);
for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){
            list.push({'list':list[i] });
        } 
//alert gives me an expected answer (122) but in display only 30 are available.
//JQGRID CODE
jQuery("#jqGrid1").jqGrid({ 
            datatype: "local",
            data: list,
            width : 600,
            height: 600, 
            shrinkToFit: false,
            forceFit: true,
            colModel: [
                { label: 'List', name: 'list', index: 'list', width: 350, align: 'left', classes:'zeroBorderRight' }
            ],
            gridComplete: function(){


                jQuery('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css({'height':'auto', 'max-height':'100px'}); 
                jQuery('.ui-th-column').css({'background':'#F2F2F2','height':'25px','text-align':'left'});
                jQuery('.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td').css({'height':'20px'});

                 $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow").removeClass("myAltRowClassEven myAltRowClassOdd");
                 $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow:odd").addClass("myAltRowClassEven");
                 $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow:even").addClass("myAltRowClassOdd");
                 $('.ui-corner-all').addClass('ui-zero-corner');

            },
            onSortCol: function (index, columnIndex, sortOrder) {
                $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow").removeClass("myAltRowClassEven myAltRowClassOdd");
                $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow:odd").addClass("myAltRowClassEven");
                 $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow:even").addClass("myAltRowClassOdd");
            }
        });
```

Comment: You need to show your code, there's no way for us to know what you might be doing wrong. Also, jqgrid paginates, have you tried going to the next page of the display?

Comment: Is JQGrid one of those controls that automatically provides paging, and thus *deliberately* shows only 30 at a time?

Comment: @Barmar hi. I have edited the post and added the code. And there is no pagination in displaying the list. Is there any default feature in JQGris which just shows 30?

Comment: Show your jQgrid code that displays the grid.

Comment: The `rowNum` option specifies the maximum number of rows displayed in the grid. It defaults to 20.

Comment: @Barmar I have added the JQGRID code. Also can you please let me know where will be specify the rowNum??

Comment: It's one of the jQgrid options, just like `width`.

Comment: You don't seem to be using `datagrid1` in the grid, it's using `list`.

Comment: I have corrected the list name. @Barmar ..Can you please let me know if loadOnce: true option is related to this?

Comment: Are you really pushing elements of `list` back into the same array?

Comment: `loadOnce` is only relevant if you're loading from the server, not local data.

Comment: oh okay. I have added the numRows property and its working fine now. Thanks a lot @Barmar for you immediate response. :)